# Extending Illuminate\Http\Request clears Accept header

Tags: json, laravel, request, laravel-5.1, http-accept-header

I've extended the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class and am passing it along to my controller.

In my controller, I check if the request has an `Accept: application/json` header, using the `$request->wantsJson()` method.

If I use the base `Illuminate\Http\Request` class it works perfectly fine, but if I use my extended class, it says that the Accept header is null.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyRequest extends Request
{
   ...
}
```

Controller

```
class MyController
{
    public function search(MyRequest $request) {
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            // return json
        }
        // return view
    }
}
```

This does not work. If I instead replace `MyRequest` with an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request` it works. If I var_dump `$request->header('Accept')`, it's NULL when using MyRequest.

Comment: Do you have a __construct() method in your MyRequest class?

Comment: @EricMakesStuff no i do not. I even removed all the methods and made it a blank class just to see, and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest` instead:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MyRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

The [`FormRequestServiceProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/FormRequestServiceProvider.php) performs a series of configuration steps that set up the request. You could replicate that in your own service provider, of course.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. Actually I had originally extended `FormRequest` but then wanted it to be accessible by guests, so the `function authorize()` thing was what I really needed